# Issue with undefined javascript function related to asynchronous and synchronous functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, callback, undefined

Currently I'm working on a project that retrieves data from the twitch.tv API. I have two functions– one that's classifying whether a user is active, inactive or dead (has deleted their account) and another that is getting specific data depending on the status of the user. For example, if while running the `classification` function I find that `user1` is active, then using the `profile` function I'll retrieving his/her profile picture and bio. I'm storing the string value returned from the `profile` function in the `add` variable, however `console.log(add)` shows up as undefined. My code is below. Any explanation or solution would be much appreciated! I'm a newbie at Javascript so a simplistic explanation would be great!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var users= ["freecodecamp", "storbeck", "terakilobyte", "habathcx","RobotCaleb","thomasballinger","noobs2ninjas","beohoff", "MedryBW", "comster404", "brunofin"];
classification(users);

function classification(arr){
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        (function(i) {
        $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+arr[i]+"?callback=?", function (data){
            var code="";
            if(data.stream) {
                var add= profile(arr[i], data.stream);

                code="<div id='"+arr[i]+"' class='active'><a href='http://www.twitch.tv/"+arr[i]+"'>"+arr[i]+"</a><img class='check-icon' src='css/images/check.png'>"+add+"</div>";

                //why is add undefined??
                console.log(add);
                $("#content").append(code);

            } else if (data.stream===null) {
                var add= profile(arr[i], data.stream);
                 code="<div id='"+arr[i]+"' class='inactive'><a href='http://www.twitch.tv/"+arr[i]+"'>"+arr[i]+"</a><img class='x-icon' src='css/images/x.png'>"+add+"</div>";
                //why is add undefined??
                console.log(add);
                $("#content").append(code);

            } else if (data.error) {
                 code="<div id='"+arr[i]+"' class='dead'>Unfortunately "+arr[i]+" has deleted their account</div>";
                $("#content").append(code);
            }

        });
     })(i);

    }


}


function profile(val, ifActive) {
    var code="";
    $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/"+val+"?callback=?", function (data){
        if(ifActive) {
            var pic= data.logo;
            var bio= data.bio;
            code="<span class='pic'><img src='"+pic+"'></span><div class='bio'>"+bio+"</div>";


            return code;

        } else if(ifActive===null) {
            var pic= data.logo;
            code="<span class='pic'><img src='"+pic+"'></span>";


            return code;

        } 
    });


}
```

});

Comment: It's because your profile function doesn't return any value. The inner Ajax call does, but what you need to do is to return a callback with the value back to classification..

Comment: You can not return from an asynchronous method. The way you have it coded, it is not going to work. Basically all the code that is after the `var add= profile(arr[i], data.stream);` line needs to be executed in the profile callback when you get the profile data back.

Comment: @epascarello Interesting... I thought that my profile function was a synchronous method. How can you tell that it's asynchronous? I'm having a little trouble understanding how to differentiate the two so any explanation or helpful links would be much appreciated!

Comment: jQuery's getJSON is not synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a callback in your profile function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var users= ["freecodecamp", "storbeck", "terakilobyte", "habathcx","RobotCaleb","thomasballinger","noobs2ninjas","beohoff", "MedryBW", "comster404", "brunofin"];
    classification(users);

    function classification(arr){
        for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            (function(i) {
                $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+arr[i]+"?callback=?", function (data){
                    var code="";
                    if(data.stream) {
                        profile(arr[i], data.stream, function(add){
                            code="<div id='"+arr[i]+"' class='active'><a href='http://www.twitch.tv/"+arr[i]+"'>"+arr[i]+"</a><img class='check-icon' src='css/images/check.png'>"+add+"</div>";

                            //why is add undefined??
                            console.log(add);
                            $("#content").append(code);
                        });


                    } else if (data.stream===null) {
                        profile(arr[i], data.stream, function(add){
                             code="<div id='"+arr[i]+"' class='inactive'><a href='http://www.twitch.tv/"+arr[i]+"'>"+arr[i]+"</a><img class='x-icon' src='css/images/x.png'>"+add+"</div>";
                            //why is add undefined??
                            console.log(add);
                            $("#content").append(code);
                        });

                    } else if (data.error) {
                         code="<div id='"+arr[i]+"' class='dead'>Unfortunately "+arr[i]+" has deleted their account</div>";
                        $("#content").append(code);
                    }

                });
            })(i);
        }
    }

    function profile(val, ifActive, callback) {
        var code="";
        $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/"+val+"?callback=?", function (data){
            if(ifActive) {
                var pic= data.logo;
                var bio= data.bio;
                code="<span class='pic'><img src='"+pic+"'></span><div class='bio'>"+bio+"</div>";
                if(typeof callback == 'function') {
                    callback(code);
                }
            } else if(ifActive===null) {
                var pic= data.logo;
                code="<span class='pic'><img src='"+pic+"'></span>";
                if(typeof callback == 'function') {
                    callback(code);
                }
            } 
        });


    }
});
```